# How the difficulty of the network affect the average block mining time if we have static hash power?

Tags: mining-theory, difficulty, hashpower

Let's suppose that I have 500 KH/s of hash power overall from my mining rig. I'm about to start mining coin **X** and its network difficulty is **Y**. Current hashrate of the whole network is 100 KH/s and calculations are showing that average time of mining one block by my rig is about 1 minute.

I've connected my rig to mine this coin and mined 10 blocks within 10 minutes and let's suppose that difficulty gradually was doubled and became **2Y**. Will my rig have to mine next block for 2 minutes instead of the last one?

Answer (score 2):

The rate of you finding blocks solely depends on your own hashrate and the network difficulty, nothing else.

The overall network hashrate influences the difficulty with a delay, which on its turn influences your rate of block finding. However, that's the only effect.